# Order object by child property

Tags: javascript, angular

In my Angular4 app, I want to sort my object (`obj`) by a child key (`order` in this case), like following:

```
var obj = {
    signal_a : {
        order : 2,
        signals : []
    },
    signal_b : {
        order : 3,
        signals : []
    },
    signal_c : {
        order : 1,
        signals : []
    }
}
```

Currently displaying:

```
1. signal_a
2. signal_b
3. signal_c
```

Wanted result:

```
1. signal_c
2. signal_a
3. signal_b
```

Comment: what did you tried??

Comment: you must make by yourself the ordering, because is not an array is an object...

Comment: JavaScript object key order is not guaranteed.

Comment: I tried looping each object, building a new array where I duplicate the objects to, and afterwards copy them back to an object... I really don't like this method...

Comment: Javascript object key order has special form, i.e. integer properties are sorted, others appear in creation order. If the object's keys are non-integer, then they are listed in the creation order.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does JavaScript Guarantee Object Property Order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using `Object.keys` to get an array of your object properties and sort them by looking their `order` and recreate a new object based on this new order.

**Warning**
As explain here : [Does JavaScript Guarantee Object Property Order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order)
JS can't guarantee the order of the object properties. You have to convert your object into array. Or use map.

```js
var obj = {
    signal_a : {
        order : 2,
        signals : []
    },
    signal_b : {
        order : 3,
        signals : []
    },
    signal_c : {
        order : 1,
        signals : []
    }
};

var orderedObj = {};
Object.keys(obj).sort((a,b) => obj[a].order > obj[b].order ? 1 : -1).forEach(prop => orderedObj[prop] = obj[prop]);
console.log(orderedObj);
```

**Object** to **array** :

```js
var obj = {
    signal_a : {
        order : 2,
        signals : []
    },
    signal_b : {
        order : 3,
        signals : []
    },
    signal_c : {
        order : 1,
        signals : []
    }
};

var objToArray = Object.keys(obj).sort((a,b) => obj[a].order > obj[b].order ? 1 : -1).map(key => {
  return {
  "key":key,
  "value":obj[key]
  };
});

console.log(objToArray);
```

Comment: You can NOT trust on the order of the keys!

Comment: Properties order in objects is not guaranteed in JavaScript; you need to use an Array or Map (ECMAScript 2015). A Map shares some similarities with an Object and guarantees the keys order. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map

Comment: Agree with you @PiotrPasieka I just give him a solution to reorder his object at a T moment. The best way is to convert him into array.

Comment: @user1141796 Update answer with an array transformation to guarantee the order.